# How to set the referer of the cloudfront file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Use Aws S3 and cloudfront now.

S3 private content.

How to set the referer of the cloudfront url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure i understand the question, but you probably want to use "signed urls" and/or "origin access identity" instead of referer header:

See doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html